# How to re-use Word Macro Ribbon in multiple systems?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a WORD Macro in VBA along with the ribbon. The ribbon works well in my system. But when I share the same macro-enabled file with others, the macros won't be seen in their system even if they have turned on the Developer Tab.

Upon research on Google, I found a workaround. That is to copy the "Normal.dotm" file of my system and paste it into others' systems. But do we have any permanent solution wherein I can create a ribbon that could be re-used by many people? If yes, how?

Please note: I am talking about MS-Word Macros.

Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: Write a Word add-in.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ : Thanks for the comment. Actually, I am new to Marcos. and Yes, I did search for creating Add-in. But I couldn't find many articles/posts around it. Do you mind letting me know more about it? maybe any link to tutorials/articles would be really helpful. We have many tutorials around MS_Excel, But that's not the case with MS Word

Comment: The worst possible thing you can do is copy your Normal.dotm to other users. How did you create the ribbon?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt : I just went to the "Customize ribbon" options under the File menu and created the ribbon by selecting my macro. So, next time when I open my word document, all I have to do is, just navigate to my ribbon and click on the macro to run. But I believe, giving Normal.dotm file to everyone is not a feasible idea. But everything works only in my system lol.

Comment: Checkout [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#how-are-office-add-ins-different-from-com-and-vsto-add-ins) and [Build your first Word task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator)

Comment: This would be better asked in the Word SuperUser forum. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word ---For creating a custom ribbon tab that is easily transferred, you need to edit the XML of a global template, which should also contain your macros. See Customize the Ribbon, It Doesn't Take Rocket Science http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html. You should not be transferring your Normal template nor your Word.OfficeUI to anyone; that is just plain abusive!

Comment: Instead of a custom ribbon tab, you could simply store your macros and QAT modifications in a global template (not your Normal.dotm). That can be done within the user interface and with no XML modification. This is my page with details on QAT modification: http://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm

Answer (score 1):

As you have used "Customize ribbon" to create your custom tab you haven't actually created a ribbon. What you have done is edited your personal UI customization file. This is a file with the extension ".officeUI" which you can find in C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office. Whilst you could possibly distribute this file you need to be aware that it stores your customizations to both the ribbon and the QAT, so you risk overwriting any customizations the user has already made.

To distribute your code to others you have three options. In order of complexity:

1. VBA add-in
2. COM add-in (aka VSTO add-in)
3. Office Add-in (aka Office Web Add-in)

To create a VBA add-in you simply need to move all your code from your "Normal.dotm" into a new template. You then save that template in the Startup folder (see File | Options | Advanced | General | File Locations to get the location).

You will of course need to create a ribbon for your template. This requires you to create an XML file which is stored inside the template. You can find some information in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Library-Reference/Concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file) from Microsoft.

There is a free [editor you can download](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor) for this from GitHub, though it doesn't provide much assistance, and a free [Excel add-in](https://andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor_2010.htm) (which also writes RibbonX for Word and PowerPoint) which makes the process much easier. You can't simply copy the XML from the officeUI file and paste it into either editor though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I shall definitely try this out and feedback here. Many thanks for your time.